# Azure AD integration with Bot Framework / teams

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, botframework

Last week I've been looking at [Bot framework Samples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore), honestly BotFx isn't my area of expertise. 
I was playing with these samples from the sample library:

```
18.bot-authentication
24.bot-authentication-msgraph
46.teams-auth
```

The required steps for making work each of them are almost the same, for #18 and make it work in the emulator this include:

- Register the BotApp in Azure AD
- Generate a Secret
- Add the Redirect URI (as documented it should be: https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect)
- Create an azure bot service
- Customize the OAuth Connection Settings

[image]

- Then in the solution Modify appsettings.json (sample values below)

```
    {
      "ConnectionName": "juank",
      "MicrosoftAppId": "cee1234562074c-1b3e-49b4-9e76-b727d73453454e018d",
      "MicrosoftAppPassword": "uxPdfgwo.JAYmgrtU]w5I7KdgxLZSJ.a[qtgtrFxYZ02"
    }
```

- After that It's required to run the emulator and configure the
  following settings

[image]

- Up to this point the bot works as expected

[image]

- Then I type any... and it just doesn't work. I receive this answer
  from the bot :

[image]

- And this data from the trace `Operation returned an invalid status
  code 'Unauthorized'`

```
{
  "channelId": "emulator",
  "conversation": {
    "id": "77631280-22e8-11ea-93e0-6dc9b0b41a7c|livechat"
  },
  "from": {
    "id": "61bab030-214b-11ea-9cf4-193735472c4b",
    "name": "Bot",
    "role": "bot"
  },
  "id": "ae429e60-22e8-11ea-9786-a543cb22378b",
  "label": "TurnError",
  "localTimestamp": "2019-12-20T00:22:13-05:00",
  "locale": "en-US",
  "name": "OnTurnError Trace",
  "recipient": {
    "id": "f6982626-923e-4fd3-b930-eabf095e96df",
    "role": "user"
  },
  "replyToId": "aacb51f0-22e8-11ea-9786-a543cb22378b",
  "serviceUrl": "https://7eec83e4.ngrok.io",
  "timestamp": "2019-12-20T05:22:13.958Z",
  "type": "trace",
  "value": "Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'",
  "valueType": "https://www.botframework.com/schemas/error"
}
```

And that's all.

I've successfully acquired the token from the OAuth setting Test tool in azure portal and also using Postman,  but i haven't been able to make these Demos work properly once OAuthCard should be presented for login. Debugging hasn't been helpful since there isn't other information apart from JSON exposed above.

Any guidance or orientation about how to fix this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to configure Azure Bot Service configurations in emulator. The Application Id and Application Password should be the same as those in appsettings.

[image]

And you should got these values from Azure portal under Configuration part.

[image]

Before doing this, please make sure the auth connection works.

[image]

**Update:**

[image]

You can change the Microsoft APPId here:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer @tony-ju . The bot stars, I mean the AppId and Secret is already configured. Then once the bot should present the login card the situation described is triggered.

Comment: @JuanK And you need two applications, one for auth, the other one for bot

Comment: The test connection works for both AD v1 and v2 @tony-ju

Comment: About the "other App" comment, could you explain little more please. @tony-ju

Comment: @JuanK It is one used when create the bot, see the update in the answer.

Comment: once created the bot, where can I change that? This is like a bug on the platform right? There shouldn't be necessary to setup the client credentials twice, one of them at the Bot Service creation only. @tony-ju

Comment: this has worked, but i'd like to clarify the whole thing to complete a report for the PG.

Comment: @JuanK You can change it under Configuration. Add the screenshot to the answer. This application is used for bot, it is different from the one used for auth.

Comment: I haven't realize where, there are the settings for "MicrosoftAppId" and "MicrosoftAppPassword" but I can't find editable settings to change the value listed under Settings just above the Analytics Section. Indeed there is a place which explicitly says "The Microsoft App ID cannot be changed. You can generate a new password by clicking on the 'Manage' link"

Comment: I thought that setting was legacy. I'm going to award you the answer, and report this as an issue to msoft. Thank you so much. I appreciate your help.